# Past Perfect or Past Simple in the sentence where there are two events

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

which option is correct in the following sentence?

> I ___ for my exam all morning so I was really upset when I didn't do
>   well.
>
> a) revised
>
> b) had revised

I would say that both options make sense. How can I understand whether I have to use past perfect (which I use for a sequence of events which happened in the past, therefore `I had revised for my exam and I was really upset`) or past simple (which I use for something that happened in the past, therefore `I revised for my exam...`) in such cases?

Does that **so** (`so I was...`) in the sentence make me somehow understand that I should opt for `past simple`, which claims to be the correct answer?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

There is **no proof here** except actually writing them  out and seeing logically that this is a "speaker's choice" issue. The two are different in emphasis:

1) I revised for my exam all morning [that is over and done with] so I was really upset when I didn't do well. [the second clause is the consequence].

I revised for my exam [a thing that is finished] and "was upset when I didn't do well", also past. etc.

COMPARED TO:

2) I had revised for my exam all morning so I was really upset when I didn't do well.

In the second instance, **you as speaker want to show a temporal sequence of activities**, as it were. 
The implication is that you "had revised for your exam all morning" [prior to taking it].
had revised → took exam - was upset by that.